# python - try/except all errors in script like php's set_error_handler

Tags: python, exception

Does python have a "catch all" solution where if an error/exception is triggered anywhere in the script the error is passed to a custom function similar to how PHP's set_error_handler() function works?

I'm familiar with the try/catch method, but it's kind of a nuissance since the try/catch only works on the immediate code within in it.

```
def sample_function():
    # some code that causes error, breaks script, does not pass error back to try/catch

try:
    sample_function()
except Exception, e: 
    print str(e)
```

I'm looking for a simple try/except **everything** even if error is triggered within a function called from within a function without having to wrap every block of code with a try/except.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: @Nix -- Blast!  And I was all proud of myself for digging `sys.excepthook` out of the documentation.  I thought to myself, "Surely I'll get some upvotes for this one"

Comment: @mgilson i gave you some love.. but it is a dupe :)

Comment: thanks guys, while searching for previous answers, should have added "global"!

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code is the main entry point. Just wrap the try/except around that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you can assign a 3 argument function to [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)